# Resize position absolute element width to content with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put elements in a horizontal row so I can scroll through them, for this I have made an inner and an outer container. The outer container has a fixed width and the inner container should have a width that is determined by it's content which can be larger than the outer div.

**HTML**

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        <ul>
            <li class="item"></li>
            <li class="item"></li>
            <li class="item"></li>
            <li class="item"></li>
            <li class="item"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#outer{
    width:250px;
    position: relative; /* required to make overflow hidden work */
     overflow:hidden;  /* commented to demonstrate the issue */
    background-color: lightgreen;
    height: 80px;
}

#inner {
    position: absolute;
     width: 1000px; /* <- needs to scale to content */
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.item:first-child{
    margin-left:0;
}

.item {
    width: 100px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    margin-left: 10px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

I'm trying to solve this issue using CSS alone but I've been unsuccesful so far. *For this issue, browser compatibility is a non-issue.*

[image: What I have]

*What I have*

[image: What I want]

*What I want*

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qczj9Lsd/8/)

Comment: Your "What i want"/"What i have" is unclear. 
When opening your fiddle, I see the result of the second picture which I interpret as, "what you want".

Comment: Ah yes, sorry about that. I edited my question to fix this.

Comment: You can't put `div`s in a `ul`...it's invalid HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `white-space: nowrap;` on `#inner`

[***Fiddle***](https://jsfiddle.net/qczj9Lsd/6/)

[White space property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple, thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Fester No problem. Have a look at Paulie_D's comment though. He is correct in that your code is faulty HTML. Nesting a div inside a UL will not pass a validator.

Comment: Yeah that was an error on my part, the children of the <ul> are <li> elements in my project. I messed up when creating the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

i dont't know if i get your question right, but have you tried it with

```
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qczj9Lsd/3/)

Comment: The overflowing of the div is not the issue, I know how to do that part. I want to keep the items on one row and not have them break into several rows.

Comment: I commented it out to demonstrate the issue, the line is there though

Answer (score 0):

Just make some few modifications

```
#inner{width: 750px;}
#outer{width: 250px;overflow-x: auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You HTML is invalid as divs cannot be children of a `ul`.

In fact, I'm not sure you need the `ul` at all as you can achieve what you are after without it.

I have widened the outer div in the Fiddle so you can see what is going on

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/qczj9Lsd/7/)

```css
#outer {
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 80px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#inner {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
}
.item:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">

    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh right, I made this issue when creating the fiddle, they're actually <li> elements in my project.